# Weighted choices

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there a more efficient way to do the below without two for loops in actionscript 3? In java there is NavigableMap or something like that where dont need to loop.

```
var treasureItemsWeights:Object = { "1" : 5 , "2" : 20, "3" : 400, "4" : 60, "5" : 20, 
                                            "6" : 20 ,  "7" : 20 ,  "8" : 20 ,  "9" : 20} ;

function chooseTreasureItem():String 
{
    var total = 0; 
    for (var key:String in treasureItemsWeights) 
    {
        total += treasureItemsWeights[key];
    }
    var num:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (total+1));
    total = 0;
    for (var key:String in treasureItemsWeights) 
    {
        total += treasureItemsWeights[key];
        if (num<=total) 
        {
            return key;
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Treasure Item

The fact that you have a variable named `treasureItemsWeights` and that your function returns the `key` tells me that you might have other variables, such as `treasureItemsValue` or `treasureItemsType` and `treasureItemsCount`, `treasureItemsPosition` etc. If you do, this is a bad idea.

You should have a `TreasureItem` *class* with the *properties* `weight`, `value`, `type` and `count` (or whatever properties you need). Having a `TreasureItem` class would allow you to store all the information about a single `TreasureItem` together.

```
var treasureItems: Vector.<TreasureItem> = new <TreasureItem>[
   new TreasureItem(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), // type, value, position... whatever.
   new TreasureItem(2, 3, 4, 5, 6), // type, value, position... whatever.
   new TreasureItem(3, 4, 5, 6, 7), // type, value, position... whatever.
];
```

#### Efficiency

The best performance gain I can recommend would be to consider caching the `total` value that is calculated in the first loop, as I have a feeling that value will not change very often (if it will change at all).

#### Choose Treasure Item - skewed randomness

Now that you have a `TreasureItem` class, you can return the `TreasureItem` directly, instead of returning its key.

Also, your `Math.floor(Math.random() * (total+1));` is wrong. Imagine that you have the weights `2, 3, 4` which adds up to 9, then you are randomizing a number from 0 to 9 (inclusive), and then iterating and adding to `total` again and comparing with `num <= total`, now let's see the distribution:

```
Num -- item chosen
0 1 2 -- first item
3 4 5 -- second item
6 7 8 9 -- third item
```

So you see, your first item now has the same weight as the second item. This was not intended.

The correct way would be to use `Math.floor(Math.random() * total);` which will randomize a number from 0 to 8 (inclusive), and then iterating and adding to `total` again and comparing with `num < total`, now let's see the distribution:

```
Num -- item chosen
0 1 -- first item
2 3 4 -- second item
5 6 7 8 -- third item
```

That matches the weights exactly.

Here's what we end up with:

```
function chooseTreasureItem():String 
{
    var total = 0; 
    for (var item : TreasureItem in treasureItems) 
    {
        total += item.weight;
    }
    var num: Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * total);
    total = 0;
    for (var item : TreasureItem in treasureItems) 
    {
        total += item.weight;
        if (num < total) 
        {
            return item;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, before i saw your answer i already changed to a class and cached the total, you are right about getting the num, which i will update. I guess there is no way then by using a hashtable type structure and getting constant time lookup and avoiding loops?

Comment: @tsukimi How many treasure items do you have? It is theoretically possible to put it in a tree structure to get O(log n) lookup time, but I don't think it is worth it.

Comment: At the moment i only have around 30, i was just curious of a way to avoid for loops in as3